Bounding box intersection when crossing date-line and meridian
First of all, I check for general intersections:
     public bool CheckOverlap(BoundingBox boundingBox)
     {
     if (this.UpperRight.Longitude < boundingBox.LowerLeft.Longitude)
        return false;
     if (this.LowerLeft.Longitude > boundingBox.UpperRight.Longitude)
        return false;
     if (this.UpperRight.Latitude < boundingBox.LowerLeft.Latitude)
        return false;
     if (this.LowerLeft.Latitude > boundingBox.UpperRight.Latitude)
        return false;
     return true;
     }

But I also have to deal with the international date-line. Any suggestions to how to account for this -- I'm kinda lost at the moment. I was thinking that a way of detecting whether a bounding box crosses the dateline is to check if one of the coordinate's longitude is positive and the other negative. For example, if we have a coordinate (1, -160) and (1, 160), we know it crosses.
The bounding box is basically made of two coordinates with longitudes and then latitudes which is between -180 and 180. We have a LowerLeft and an Upperright to determine the bounding box. We determine the lowerleft coordinate from two given coordinates by comparing their latitude and longitude values using a min function. We do the same to get the upperRight coordinate by using a max function for both latitude and longitude. Using this we have the lowerleft and upperright coordinates for the bounding box, thus we can use the above logic to check for intersections. However, I'm in doubt with crossing the dateline, because we go from -180 to +180 and the other way around.
Some examples

General Case

In this case it isn't an issue. If we were to make a bounding box of the two, this would be lower and upper. Meaning, if we were to compare to another box we'd say for example if Other.UpperRight.Long is less than This.Lower.Long, we know they cannot intersect.

Crossing Date-Line

However, if the two coordinates from which we make the bounding-box actually cross. Then the lowerleft, would be on the right side (cus we check max/min) and upperright would be to the left of it. Meaning, that if we have another, which upper right is like stated in the picture, then we would say, because upper right is left of lowerleft, which would normally mean they can't intersect, but in this scenario it obviously can.
Constraints

All coordinates are between -180 and 180 (no need for normalization)


The UK runs from -5 to +3 but doesn't cross the anti meridian

Hi. I'm sorry, I dropped the ball when your question was on Stack Overflow. Have you solved it, yet?
